# Particular java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

How would I check that a String input in Java has the format:

xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

where x is a digit 0..9?

Thanks!

Comment: Deleted my answer - I read "JavaScript" in my head :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String objects in Java have a [`matches`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method which can check against a regular expression:

```
 myString.matches("^\\d{4}(-\\d{4}){3}$")
```

This particular expression checks for four digits, and then three times (a hyphen and four digits), thus representing your required format.

Comment: Note: I edited it just again because I left out the anchors. Use the anchored version, not the one without.

Comment: Why couldn't this be reduced to :

myString.matches("(-\\d{4}){4}");

Comment: @Amir: Because your string would have to start with a hyphen then.

Comment: Contra-nitpick: Java regexps are by default anchored `;)`

Comment: @Balus: Eek! Ok, that's news to me. Though to be fair I never used them in Java so far anyway. So out of curiosity: How do you do an unanchored match, then? Pre- and append `.*`?

Answer (score 4):

To start, this is a great source of regexps: http://www.regular-expressions.info. Visit it, poke and play around. Further the `java.util.Pattern` API has a concise [overview](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) of regex patterns.

Now, back to your question: you want to match four consecutive groups of four digits separated by a hyphen. A single group of 4 digits can in regex be represented as

```
\d{4}
```

Four of those separated by a hyphen can be represented as:

```
\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}
```

To make it shorter you can also represent a single group of four digits and three consecutive groups of four digits prefixed with a hyphen:

```
\d{4}(-\d{4}){3}
```

Now, in Java you can use [`String#matches()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) to test whether a string matches the given regex.

```
boolean matches = value.matches("\\d{4}(-\\d{4}){3}");
```

Note that I escaped the backslashes `\` by another backslash `\`, because the backslashes have a special meaning in `String`. To represent the *actual* backslash, you'd have to use `\\`.

Comment: They don't have a special meaning to the String class. They have a special meaning for the compiler.

Comment: Geez, I put 3 minutes of effort in and there's already an accepted answer.

Comment: +1 for the effort, though. I tend to no longer do that with trivial questions exactly for that reason ;-). Except for batch files where I still have a hope of being the first to answer correctly and thoroughly :-)